# Annotations with Material Column Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have data in the form of

`[[X, Y, {role: "annotation"}], [1,2, "something"], ...,...]`

that I pass to

`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataPattern);` and plot with

```
var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('distribution-over-range'));
material.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

The annotations fail to appear. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

`google.charts.Bar` component does not support [annotations role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) but you could utilize `google.visualization.BarChart` from `corechart` package for that purpose as demonstrated below:

```js
      //google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Opening Move', 'Percentage', { role: "style" }, { role: 'annotation' }],
          ["King's pawn (e4)", 44, "#b87333",'43%'],
          ["Queen's pawn (d4)", 31, "silver", '31%'],
          ["Knight to King 3 (Nf3)", 12, "gold", '12%'],
          ["Queen's bishop pawn (c4)", 10, "color: #e5e4e2", '10%'],
          ['Other', 3, "green", '3%']
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Chess opening moves',
          width: 900,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: { title: 'Chess opening moves',
                   subtitle: 'popularity by percentage' },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
        };

        //var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("top_x_div"));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      };
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="top_x_div" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div>
```

Comment: I'm still facing this issue I'm using Material Bar Chart as it matches my requirements, I can't use stacked and un stacked charts together in visualization.BarChart, so is there any solution?